# CSS Smooth scrolling property not working

Tags: html, css, smooth-scrolling

I know it's a question asked by many people but after dozens of posts I still cannot figure out the answer to this.

I have a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JEFDocs | All Docs | Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/module.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="logo" href="index.html">JEF<span>Docs</span></a>

            <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Open Navigation">

            <nav>
                <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Close Navigation">
                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="docs.html">All Docs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/orgs/JEF-Napoli/dashboard">GitHub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="docs-content">
        <div class="left-space">
            <p>In this page</p>
            <ul class="left-nav">
                <li><a href="#1">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-space">
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <h1 id="1">Main Title</h1>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>
                Paragraph
                With code:
                <pre><code class="pyton">print("Hello world")
x=10
print(x)</code></pre>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum saepe expedita commodi consectetur ipsum. Deleniti delectus, quas voluptatibus eum dolore accusamus aliquid voluptate a error sunt dolores mollitia. At, mollitia.
            A nulla eligendi provident exercitationem! Minus perspiciatis eum vel similique, ducimus illum qui sint magnam, asperiores adipisci nesciunt in, rem assumenda repellendus! Blanditiis corporis, quidem dolore expedita consectetur aliquid eius!
            Similique, provident illo nihil, unde iure perspiciatis corrupti, eius ad sint consequuntur asperiores error harum? Laborum beatae in dolorem ullam itaque quos deleniti quae debitis, magnam autem ipsa deserunt? Illo!
            Nesciunt perspiciatis a corporis necessitatibus sed asperiores voluptas error saepe tempora rem voluptatibus quae ipsa molestias soluta nostrum, non sunt accusamus fuga numquam ut illo dicta! Deleniti magni doloribus ea.
            Odio, quas fugiat harum eos animi suscipit dolorum ipsam aliquid perspiciatis, vitae quam assumenda soluta voluptas delectus? Placeat, repellat. Voluptatibus sint blanditiis explicabo similique, exercitationem et tempora consequatur ex asperiores!
            Animi vel dignissimos inventore eligendi quisquam alias vitae earum itaque neque fugiat rem amet culpa atque delectus quod, tenetur praesentium in autem porro quam qui reprehenderit! Corrupti soluta qui illum.
            Ut at sint, eius aperiam vitae, magni vel harum distinctio excepturi iusto laborum itaque deserunt cumque eaque. Qui ex quas blanditiis repellat, temporibus ab inventore perferendis sapiente cum quo laborum?
            Sunt tempora possimus culpa odit numquam, nobis commodi quod, vero repellat autem nostrum laboriosam. Consequuntur hic excepturi in amet unde voluptatibus a? Optio officia obcaecati voluptatem quod dolores minus doloribus?
            Nihil alias nesciunt veniam modi similique blanditiis officiis, ratione obcaecati dolores aliquid quos iusto ducimus excepturi voluptas expedita, laboriosam corrupti illum quibusdam doloribus quaerat? Quaerat neque quia impedit atque vel.
            Veritatis placeat officia maiores inventore laborum illo enim vitae, ratione, dolorem esse est! Omnis, libero facere eaque vitae fuga ullam cumque consequatur porro ab recusandae, soluta facilis? Quasi, rem voluptate?
            Soluta eius molestiae nemo, maiores dolore ratione placeat! Esse, doloribus tempora sint sed rem reiciendis corrupti. Sit mollitia veniam tempora iusto ipsa voluptate quod, eaque veritatis quasi iste hic quas!
            Corporis pariatur, esse ipsum labore alias accusamus voluptatem veritatis ipsa possimus deserunt veniam deleniti facilis aliquam magni quidem, eligendi tempore ab dicta amet optio nesciunt provident voluptas eaque? Inventore, ducimus.
            Numquam, deserunt voluptatibus veritatis est omnis ducimus ab tempora cupiditate fuga deleniti officiis velit molestiae facilis eveniet debitis, reprehenderit iure repellendus impedit animi dolorum culpa nostrum rerum illo! Quidem, soluta.
            Corrupti sapiente eius necessitatibus nostrum incidunt, modi, in quae accusantium totam minima ducimus, aperiam nulla velit eos. Adipisci dignissimos eveniet, quia, voluptatibus unde repellat aperiam doloremque mollitia fugiat minus dolor.
            Maxime sequi pariatur, quod, esse animi placeat quibusdam excepturi doloremque consectetur culpa commodi enim. Autem voluptas quasi excepturi natus laborum quas ad voluptatibus adipisci repellendus quia, ratione minus cupiditate itaque.
            Voluptate repellendus id molestiae ipsam impedit aspernatur facere magni. Eveniet aut praesentium officiis ea fugit tenetur pariatur, veritatis deserunt! Beatae, vero odit. Aliquam delectus ipsam maxime repellat tenetur, doloribus iure.
            Aspernatur vel suscipit sequi enim recusandae ratione perspiciatis, facere, fugiat incidunt, error iusto quibusdam consectetur eos. Quasi vel neque aperiam aliquid rerum, facilis cupiditate deleniti voluptate modi, nihil sunt distinctio.
</p> 
            <h1 id="2">Second Title</h1>
<p>   
            Id totam deleniti sit, magni praesentium velit voluptatum, molestias, recusandae nulla ratione quae blanditiis numquam! Sapiente nam unde quidem. Id dolor libero ipsam dolore incidunt corrupti omnis dolorem! Tempora, impedit?
            Officia at cum libero unde ipsa veritatis obcaecati est quod delectus sequi voluptatem veniam consequatur sit nobis eveniet eos ab dolore earum vero, molestias nam! Ducimus optio harum necessitatibus debitis.
            Dignissimos quo aspernatur iste, itaque vel voluptates fugiat dolorem maiores assumenda repellat accusamus, illo praesentium tempora aliquid sed doloribus provident, optio quia nihil. Consectetur optio quisquam eum deserunt nostrum delectus.
            At libero odio suscipit quae veniam possimus dolores eum praesentium aliquid illo, voluptates similique, dignissimos, magni alias debitis harum nemo. Officia, vel! Quis minima, nesciunt eos ipsum rem quos sed!
            Ad possimus error, iste facere aut voluptatem odit, voluptatum ea eos fugiat, quas cupiditate? Dolores architecto doloribus repudiandae necessitatibus repellendus officia tenetur perspiciatis, modi fugiat aliquam, tempora unde maiores doloremque.
            A, nam id et adipisci nostrum natus eligendi ducimus est quos sed eveniet? Nobis saepe placeat optio natus, atque est eius nesciunt, quaerat deleniti velit consequatur laborum molestiae error dolore?
            Ducimus, quam nostrum ipsam ex dolores maxime impedit corrupti deserunt dolor quod similique. Sed nihil explicabo laudantium a aut provident, ex pariatur aspernatur minus cupiditate saepe accusamus, expedita impedit iste!
            Vero vel iure, quaerat unde dolore tempora molestias eum facilis cumque consequuntur non totam aperiam cum voluptas qui nihil incidunt fugiat aliquid! Ipsum accusantium vero quod, fugiat soluta illum recusandae.
            Facere veniam ut est, tempora suscipit temporibus esse exercitationem reiciendis ipsam eaque dolorum, maiores dolorem ducimus voluptatem accusantium. Dicta dolorem reiciendis rerum explicabo sint pariatur illum tenetur. Laborum, tenetur repellat!
            Inventore, optio quas necessitatibus consectetur atque temporibus porro dolorem dicta incidunt eaque et unde animi! Rem eaque unde placeat accusantium repudiandae blanditiis, quod voluptate natus fuga, nisi sit adipisci totam?
            Explicabo consequuntur tempore dignissimos, debitis odit mollitia incidunt atque animi esse facere, ipsa ducimus repellendus deserunt laboriosam aliquam. Autem repudiandae voluptate dicta, reiciendis quos iusto voluptates ipsum rem iure incidunt!
 </p>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta')
              nav = document.querySelector('nav')
              mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit')
              ul = document.querySelector('ul')
              menuArrow = document.getElementById('menu-arrow');

        mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.add('menu-btn')
        })
        mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('menu-btn')
        })

        function scrollToTop() {
            window.scrollTo({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And a css file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
:root {
  --primary-color: #3272B8;
  --secondary-color: #132F47;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.docs-content .left-space {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: .5em;
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  -webkit-animation: transitionIn 1s;
          animation: transitionIn 1s;
}

.docs-content .left-space .left-nav {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.docs-content .left-space p {
  margin-left: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
}

.docs-content .left-space a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.docs-content .left-space a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

@-webkit-keyframes transitionRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
            transform: translateX(90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes transitionRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
            transform: translateX(90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.docs-content .right-space {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  -webkit-animation: transitionRight 1s;
          animation: transitionRight 1s;
}

.docs-content .right-space h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .docs-content .right-space {
    padding: 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .docs-content {
    margin: 3em auto;
    width: 1080px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space {
    height: 65.9vh;
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    margin-right: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
    padding: 2em;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: .3em;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav {
    border: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav a:hover {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .docs-content .right-space {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 66%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: var(--primary-color);
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=module.css.map */
```

The problem I'm facing is that the  `html{scroll-behavior: smooth;}` is not working at all.

I am also going to include the "main.css" (used to style the navbar at the top) file so that everybody can run this and help me:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@-webkit-keyframes opacityIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacityIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
            transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
            transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #3272B8;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

a {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

.navbar .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar .logo span {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.navbar nav {
  display: none;
}

.navbar .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .mobile-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.left-col h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-top: .2em;
  -webkit-animation: transitionIn 1s;
          animation: transitionIn 1s;
}

.left-col .primary-cta {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  border: 3px var(--primary-color) solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .6em 1.3em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.left-col .primary-cta:hover, .left-col .primary-cta:focus {
  background-color: #F2F2F2F2;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  border: 3px var(--primary-color) solid;
}

.hero-img {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: opacityIn 3s;
          animation: opacityIn 3s;
}

nav.menu-btn {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #20272E;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul.primary-nav {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: right;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-menu-exit {
  float: right;
  margin: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-menu, .mobile-menu-exit {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 180px auto;
        grid-template-columns: 180px auto;
  }
  .navbar nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    background: none;
    position: unset;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar nav ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar nav a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .1em 1em;
  }
  .navbar nav ul.primary-nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .hero-img {
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 6em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .container {
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  section {
    padding: 4em 4em;
  }
  .hero .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .hero .container .left-col {
    margin: 0 3em 0 5em;
  }
  .hero .container .left-col h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .hero-img {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 8em;
  }
  .hero-cta {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta')
              nav = document.querySelector('nav')
              mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit')
              ul = document.querySelector('ul')
              menuArrow = document.getElementById('menu-arrow');

        mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.add('menu-btn')
        })
        mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('menu-btn')
        })

        function scrollToTop() {
            window.scrollTo({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        }
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
:root {
  --primary-color: #3272B8;
  --secondary-color: #132F47;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: var(--primary-color);
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.docs-content .left-space {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 90%;
  padding: .5em;
  background: var(--secondary-color);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  -webkit-animation: transitionIn 1s;
          animation: transitionIn 1s;
}

.docs-content .left-space .left-nav {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.docs-content .left-space p {
  margin-left: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
}

.docs-content .left-space a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.docs-content .left-space a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

@-webkit-keyframes transitionRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
            transform: translateX(90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes transitionRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(90px);
            transform: translateX(90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.docs-content .right-space {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  -webkit-animation: transitionRight 1s;
          animation: transitionRight 1s;
}

.docs-content .right-space h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .docs-content .right-space {
    padding: 1em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .docs-content {
    margin: 3em auto;
    width: 1080px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space {
    height: 65.9vh;
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    margin-right: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
    padding: 2em;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: .3em;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav {
    border: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .docs-content .left-space .left-nav a:hover {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .docs-content .right-space {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 66%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
  }
  .right-space::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: var(--primary-color);
  }
}
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
@-webkit-keyframes opacityIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacityIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
            transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes transitionIn {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-90px);
            transform: translateX(-90px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

:root {
  --primary-color: #3272B8;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

a {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

.navbar .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar .logo span {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.navbar nav {
  display: none;
}

.navbar .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .mobile-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.left-col h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-top: .2em;
  -webkit-animation: transitionIn 1s;
          animation: transitionIn 1s;
}

.left-col .primary-cta {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  border: 3px var(--primary-color) solid;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .6em 1.3em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.left-col .primary-cta:hover, .left-col .primary-cta:focus {
  background-color: #F2F2F2F2;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  border: 3px var(--primary-color) solid;
}

.hero-img {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: opacityIn 3s;
          animation: opacityIn 3s;
}

nav.menu-btn {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 66%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #20272E;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul.primary-nav {
  margin-top: 5em;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: right;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mobile-menu-exit {
  float: right;
  margin: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-menu, .mobile-menu-exit {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 180px auto;
        grid-template-columns: 180px auto;
  }
  .navbar nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    background: none;
    position: unset;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar nav ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar nav a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .1em 1em;
  }
  .navbar nav ul.primary-nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .hero-img {
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 6em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  .container {
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  section {
    padding: 4em 4em;
  }
  .hero .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .hero .container .left-col {
    margin: 0 3em 0 5em;
  }
  .hero .container .left-col h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .hero-img {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 8em;
  }
  .hero-cta {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JEFDocs | All Docs | Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/module.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="logo" href="index.html">JEF<span>Docs</span></a>

            <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Open Navigation">

            <nav>
                <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Close Navigation">
                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="docs.html">All Docs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/orgs/JEF-Napoli/dashboard">GitHub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="docs-content">
        <div class="left-space">
            <p>In this page</p>
            <ul class="left-nav">
                <li><a href="#1">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-space">
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <h1 id="1">Main Title</h1>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>
                Paragraph
                With code:
                <pre><code class="pyton">print("Hello world")
x=10
print(x)</code></pre>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum saepe expedita commodi consectetur ipsum. Deleniti delectus, quas voluptatibus eum dolore accusamus aliquid voluptate a error sunt dolores mollitia. At, mollitia.
            A nulla eligendi provident exercitationem! Minus perspiciatis eum vel similique, ducimus illum qui sint magnam, asperiores adipisci nesciunt in, rem assumenda repellendus! Blanditiis corporis, quidem dolore expedita consectetur aliquid eius!
            Similique, provident illo nihil, unde iure perspiciatis corrupti, eius ad sint consequuntur asperiores error harum? Laborum beatae in dolorem ullam itaque quos deleniti quae debitis, magnam autem ipsa deserunt? Illo!
            Nesciunt perspiciatis a corporis necessitatibus sed asperiores voluptas error saepe tempora rem voluptatibus quae ipsa molestias soluta nostrum, non sunt accusamus fuga numquam ut illo dicta! Deleniti magni doloribus ea.
            Odio, quas fugiat harum eos animi suscipit dolorum ipsam aliquid perspiciatis, vitae quam assumenda soluta voluptas delectus? Placeat, repellat. Voluptatibus sint blanditiis explicabo similique, exercitationem et tempora consequatur ex asperiores!
            Animi vel dignissimos inventore eligendi quisquam alias vitae earum itaque neque fugiat rem amet culpa atque delectus quod, tenetur praesentium in autem porro quam qui reprehenderit! Corrupti soluta qui illum.
            Ut at sint, eius aperiam vitae, magni vel harum distinctio excepturi iusto laborum itaque deserunt cumque eaque. Qui ex quas blanditiis repellat, temporibus ab inventore perferendis sapiente cum quo laborum?
            Sunt tempora possimus culpa odit numquam, nobis commodi quod, vero repellat autem nostrum laboriosam. Consequuntur hic excepturi in amet unde voluptatibus a? Optio officia obcaecati voluptatem quod dolores minus doloribus?
            Nihil alias nesciunt veniam modi similique blanditiis officiis, ratione obcaecati dolores aliquid quos iusto ducimus excepturi voluptas expedita, laboriosam corrupti illum quibusdam doloribus quaerat? Quaerat neque quia impedit atque vel.
            Veritatis placeat officia maiores inventore laborum illo enim vitae, ratione, dolorem esse est! Omnis, libero facere eaque vitae fuga ullam cumque consequatur porro ab recusandae, soluta facilis? Quasi, rem voluptate?
            Soluta eius molestiae nemo, maiores dolore ratione placeat! Esse, doloribus tempora sint sed rem reiciendis corrupti. Sit mollitia veniam tempora iusto ipsa voluptate quod, eaque veritatis quasi iste hic quas!
            Corporis pariatur, esse ipsum labore alias accusamus voluptatem veritatis ipsa possimus deserunt veniam deleniti facilis aliquam magni quidem, eligendi tempore ab dicta amet optio nesciunt provident voluptas eaque? Inventore, ducimus.
            Numquam, deserunt voluptatibus veritatis est omnis ducimus ab tempora cupiditate fuga deleniti officiis velit molestiae facilis eveniet debitis, reprehenderit iure repellendus impedit animi dolorum culpa nostrum rerum illo! Quidem, soluta.
            Corrupti sapiente eius necessitatibus nostrum incidunt, modi, in quae accusantium totam minima ducimus, aperiam nulla velit eos. Adipisci dignissimos eveniet, quia, voluptatibus unde repellat aperiam doloremque mollitia fugiat minus dolor.
            Maxime sequi pariatur, quod, esse animi placeat quibusdam excepturi doloremque consectetur culpa commodi enim. Autem voluptas quasi excepturi natus laborum quas ad voluptatibus adipisci repellendus quia, ratione minus cupiditate itaque.
            Voluptate repellendus id molestiae ipsam impedit aspernatur facere magni. Eveniet aut praesentium officiis ea fugit tenetur pariatur, veritatis deserunt! Beatae, vero odit. Aliquam delectus ipsam maxime repellat tenetur, doloribus iure.
            Aspernatur vel suscipit sequi enim recusandae ratione perspiciatis, facere, fugiat incidunt, error iusto quibusdam consectetur eos. Quasi vel neque aperiam aliquid rerum, facilis cupiditate deleniti voluptate modi, nihil sunt distinctio.
</p> 
            <h1 id="2">Second Title</h1>
<p>   
            Id totam deleniti sit, magni praesentium velit voluptatum, molestias, recusandae nulla ratione quae blanditiis numquam! Sapiente nam unde quidem. Id dolor libero ipsam dolore incidunt corrupti omnis dolorem! Tempora, impedit?
            Officia at cum libero unde ipsa veritatis obcaecati est quod delectus sequi voluptatem veniam consequatur sit nobis eveniet eos ab dolore earum vero, molestias nam! Ducimus optio harum necessitatibus debitis.
            Dignissimos quo aspernatur iste, itaque vel voluptates fugiat dolorem maiores assumenda repellat accusamus, illo praesentium tempora aliquid sed doloribus provident, optio quia nihil. Consectetur optio quisquam eum deserunt nostrum delectus.
            At libero odio suscipit quae veniam possimus dolores eum praesentium aliquid illo, voluptates similique, dignissimos, magni alias debitis harum nemo. Officia, vel! Quis minima, nesciunt eos ipsum rem quos sed!
            Ad possimus error, iste facere aut voluptatem odit, voluptatum ea eos fugiat, quas cupiditate? Dolores architecto doloribus repudiandae necessitatibus repellendus officia tenetur perspiciatis, modi fugiat aliquam, tempora unde maiores doloremque.
            A, nam id et adipisci nostrum natus eligendi ducimus est quos sed eveniet? Nobis saepe placeat optio natus, atque est eius nesciunt, quaerat deleniti velit consequatur laborum molestiae error dolore?
            Ducimus, quam nostrum ipsam ex dolores maxime impedit corrupti deserunt dolor quod similique. Sed nihil explicabo laudantium a aut provident, ex pariatur aspernatur minus cupiditate saepe accusamus, expedita impedit iste!
            Vero vel iure, quaerat unde dolore tempora molestias eum facilis cumque consequuntur non totam aperiam cum voluptas qui nihil incidunt fugiat aliquid! Ipsum accusantium vero quod, fugiat soluta illum recusandae.
            Facere veniam ut est, tempora suscipit temporibus esse exercitationem reiciendis ipsam eaque dolorum, maiores dolorem ducimus voluptatem accusantium. Dicta dolorem reiciendis rerum explicabo sint pariatur illum tenetur. Laborum, tenetur repellat!
            Inventore, optio quas necessitatibus consectetur atque temporibus porro dolorem dicta incidunt eaque et unde animi! Rem eaque unde placeat accusantium repudiandae blanditiis, quod voluptate natus fuga, nisi sit adipisci totam?
            Explicabo consequuntur tempore dignissimos, debitis odit mollitia incidunt atque animi esse facere, ipsa ducimus repellendus deserunt laboriosam aliquam. Autem repudiandae voluptate dicta, reiciendis quos iusto voluptates ipsum rem iure incidunt!
 </p>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Works as expected for me. If you are wondering why the inner scroll isn't smooth, you need to set the scroll behavior on the inner container as well. Add the appropriate css.

```css
.right-space {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: When I go to full screen on your code and click `Item1` or `Item2` the page does not smooth scroll to those sections but rather jumps. That may be what he's referring to.

Comment: @Justin I think you're right. Added the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add `smooth` to the `.right-space` so when full screen you get smooth scrolling.

```
.docs-content .right-space {
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.514);
  -webkit-animation: transitionRight 1s;
          animation: transitionRight 1s;
}
```